# Горизонтальное переключение div

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Есть страница. В левой части div в котором размещено 4 ссылки. При клике на одну из ссылок, в div`e справа переключается до соответствующего div`a. К примеру, кликнули на 3, появился div 33. Как такого добиться на css? А если не добиться с css, то на js. Группа div`ов справа, с цифрами, размещена горизонтально, соответственно прокрутка желательна такая же или, если возможно, позже переделываемая в вертикальную.

```css
.one {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.three {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.four {
  min-width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">11</div>
    <div class="four">22</div>
    <div class="four">33</div>
    <div class="four">44</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: уже все за вас написано, берите да копируйте

Comment: Немного не то. Там нет возможности перематывания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('p'),
  three = document.querySelectorAll('.three')[0];
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    three.className = 'three';
    three.classList.add('three-' + i);
  })

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

.one {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #272727;
  z-index: 5;
}

.three {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-0 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.three-1 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-350px);
}

.three-2 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-700px);
}

.three-3 {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(-1050px);
}

.four {
  min-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #cd1; text-align: center;">1</p>
    <p style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #1cd; text-align: center;">2</p>
    <p style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #11d; text-align: center;">3</p>
    <p style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #d0e; text-align: center;">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three three-0">
    <div class="four" style="background: #cd1; text-align: center;">11</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #1cd; text-align: center;">22</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #11d; text-align: center;">33</div>
    <div class="four" style="background: #d0e; text-align: center;">44</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вот тут столкнулся с проблемой что в песочнице воспроизводится, а если вставить в реальные html/css/js файлы, то не работает переключение. Хотя html и css файлы обрабатываются.

Comment: @Jihhhju, а что говорит консоль? ну  у меня первая мысль, что не правильно подключен скрипт...

Comment: Да, был неверно подключен скрипт и не выставлены правила для браузеров. Разобрался. Но появилась еще проблема: при weight:100vw для .one, все съезжает. Помогает выставить на auto, Но при этом получается что в Chrome DevTools страница расползается и захватывает все дивы, когда при vw контент как и надо заполняет собой весь экран, а лишнее обрезается через overflow: hidden.

Comment: Ты лучше напиши новый вопрос... Приведи пример  проблемы...  а то так не совсем понятно...

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример на **css**. Просто поставьте классы ваши.

```css
div.tab-frame input{ display:none;}
div.tab-frame label{ display:block; float:left;padding:5px 10px; cursor:pointer}
div.tab-frame input:checked + label{ background:black; color:white; cursor:default}
div.tab-frame div.tab{ display:none; padding:5px 10px;clear:left}

div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(1),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(2),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(3){ display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="tab-frame">
  <input type="radio" checked name="tab" id="tab1">
  <label for="tab1">1</label>
    
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2">
  <label for="tab2">2</label>

 
  <div class="tab">11</div>
  <div class="tab">22</div>

</div>
```

Comment: А ничего что они в вашем примере все в одном родительском блоке, в отличии от моего, где кнопки и дивы с контентом в разных блоках?